# Jquery for hibernate many-to-one while retrieving data

Tags: jquery, hibernate, jsp

What can be written to data[i] part in jquery to get course name, I wrote data[i].course.coursename but It didn't work

Below are my models, Education and Course;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Education", schema = "xxx")
public class Education implements java.io.Serializable {

@JsonBackReference
private  Course course;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COURSEID", nullable = false)
public Course getCourse() {
    return this.course;
}

public void setCourse (Course course) {
    this.course = course;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE", schema = "xxx")
public class Course implements java.io.Serializable {

@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Education> educations = new HashSet<Education>(0);

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "course")
public Set<Education> getEducations() {
    return this.educations;
}

public void setEducations(Set<Education> educations) {
    this.educations = educations;
}
```

and jquery part for a cascading drop down

```
$('#departmentid').change(
function() {

    $.getJSON('loadCourse',{
        departmentid : $(this).val()
    }, function(data) {

        var html = '<option value="">----Select Course----</option>';
        var len = data.length;

        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            html += '<option value="' + data[i].educationid + '">' + data[i].course.coursename + ' ' + data[i].course.prefix + '</option>';

        }
        html += '</option>';
        $('#educationid').html(html);
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /* assign handler */
        /* alert(jqXHR.responseText) */
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[I found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187917/unable-to-get-manytoone-mapping-object-in-json-from-spring-hibernate)

So I added managedreference and backreference annotations to getters of manytoone relation